# DDR4 upgrade incompatibility - Dell Precision 5560 + Kingston Fury Impact

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Dell Precision 5560 with 32Gb DDR4 RAM that I want to upgrade to 64Gb. According to the system specifications, it supports up to 64Gb. The current installed RAM is 2x16Gb 3200MHz Samsung SO-DIMMS (m471a2g43bb2-cwe). Expecting no issues, I bought a pair of Kingston 32Gb 3200MHz Kingston SO-DIMMS (KF432S20IBK2/64).

Unfortunately, after I installed the new SO-DIMMS, the system won't boot. The front LED just blinks 2+5 times, which according to Dell's documentation means "incompatible memory".

Reading all the specs, I can not figure out why this memory is incompatible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the pin configuration on the old Samsung memory and your new Kingston memory.
Both should match(256/260/280/288).
Also check for supported frequency,voltage should be 1.2V and other attributes.
Run cmd and check via this below command that how much actually your system support max capacity of RAM.
*wmic memphysical get maxcapacity*.
If post running this command if it displays no. Starting from 33 or 32 then it is 32 GB max supported.
Hope this helps.